# Light scratch on sensor: is that fixable

Tags: dslr, sensor

Short question, could a very light scratch on sensor be fixed?

Comment: Are you sure it's a scratch and not just a bit of smeared dirt?

Comment: @Caleb: a line that shows a faint yellowish color, in extreme contrast(blacks to 0, white to 100). I wasn't able to fade it away with proper sensor wipes.

Comment: If you would include information on the camera in question this question could be much  more specifically answered.

Answer (score 2):

A scratched sensor can not be repaired. The only way to 'fix' the camera is to replace the sensor.

In all likelihood, though, your actual sensor is probably not scratched. What is scratched is probably the top of the stack of filters placed in front of the imaging sensor. Unfortunately, replacing a filter stack also requires extensive disassembly/reassembly of the camera that would probably cost more in labor charges than the price of all but the most expensive cameras.¹ Depending upon the specific camera and how it is made, only an already assembled sensor/filter stack combination may be available as a repair part.

<sub>¹Many different camera models cost more than a sensor/stack replacement would. But the overwhelming percentage of camera units sold are the lower cost camera models that do not cost more than the labor charge for such a repair would be.</sub>

That's not to say the camera is no longer usable at all. Depending on the location of the scratch one might be able to crop all images to exclude the area with the scratch. When selecting a lens to give a desired angle of view and when composing an image the unusable portion of the frame would need to be taken into account.

Depending on the severity of the scratch, assuming it is on the filter stack a few millimeters in front of the imaging sensor itself, shooting at very wide apertures could also minimize its effect on your images.

Comment: a camera without low pass filter, would it be filter again? how much would that cost to get it replaced approx?

Comment: Most cameras with no LPF have a cover plate with the same refractive index as a LPF. There are other filters in front of most sensors as well. UV, IR, etc.

Comment: Cost totally depends on the specific camera model and who does the work. In 2013 Roger Cicala mentioned $1,800 is what it costs LensRentals.com for a Nikon D800 sensor replacement in [this blog entry](https://www.lensrentals.com/blog/2013/02/roger-buys-a-camera-system-finally/). Keep in mind that FF sensors cost much more than APS-C sensors do, but there isn't much difference in terms of labor required.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a scratch on the filter stack on the camera's sensor, another option would be to convert the camera to an infrared camera. When that is done, the filters are replaced by other filters anyway.